# Prevent other programs from interfacing with mine

Tags: java, javafx

How would you go about preventing other programs from doing anything on your program? I have a window that opens up, however, Nvidia ShadowPlay keeps displaying in the bottom right corner. As I plan to release this I want a fix in my program that will prevent this, not a fix with shadow play since other people may have the same issue or other programs may do similar things.

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image: Image of issue]

Comment: Have you tried stagename.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at there but with this what ShadowPlay is doing is overlaying onto my program so even if it's always on top that would still show up.

Comment: Its not doing it to your program. It is probably doing it to the operating system Otherwise how would it be able to record all activity to broadcast. Bottom line is no there nothing you can do about things the operating system does to your program. Java has no concept of Nvdia Shadowplay.

Comment: Okay, I figured as much but also thought that there could be a way to set it to not allow this sort of thing or tell it that it shouldn't, whether or not it does let it. Would you have any idea about what things may cause programs like shadow play to see it as something it should interface with since I see shadow play very rarely show up on programs that are not actual games? Thanks for what you told me thus far.